# How to get value from the first/last row in grouped rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this data structure for a table with trains:

```
 from | to | connection_id | date
------+----+---------------+------
  A   | B  | 1             | some
  B   | C  | 1             | dates
  B   | D  | 2             | I can
  D   | E  | 2             | sort
  E   | C  | 2             | by
```

And I want to group the data by the connection_id column, the result I want to have is:

```
 from | to | connection_id
------+----+---------------
  A   | C  | 1            
  B   | C  | 2
```

So I want to have the from-value from the first row in the grouped rows and the to-value from the last row from the grouped rows. To get the last and first rows, there is the date column to sort by. How do I get one value from the first/last row in grouped rows?

Edit: For Clarification: For each connection_id I want to have the from-value from the row with the lowest date-value and the to-value from the row with the highest date-value.

Comment: routes are always connected? given your sample data, a simple min() and max() would work, but if you could have a row like `G, H, 2, etc` there are two separates routes for the same connection. Do you need to handle that case?

Comment: routes are alway connected, but min() and max() don't work, because there can be a train going from B via D and E to C (like in the updated sample data), min()/max() would give B and E, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If rows can be ordered by `date` field, I think you could use this:

```
select t1.`from`, t2.`to`, mm.connection_id
from (
  select connection_id, min(`date`) as minDate, max(`date`) as maxDate
  from trains
  group by connection_id) mm
  inner join trains t1 on mm.connection_id=t1.connection_id and t1.`date`=mm.minDate
  inner join trains t2 on mm.connection_id=t2.connection_id and t2.`date`=mm.maxDate
```

Here I am selecting the first and the last row of every connection_id, taking the `from` column from the first row, and the `to` column from the last. Or you could also use this trick:

```
select
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`from` ORDER BY `date`), ',', 1 ) as `from`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`to` ORDER BY `date`), ',', -1 ) as `to`,
  connection_id
from trains
group by connection_id
```

Comment: +1 @fthiella I missed out this one and thanks for the tips :) yet to update mine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `order by` on two `select` with `union`. Like the following:

```
Select * from yourtable 
group by connection_id
order by [from] desc limit 1
union
select * from yourtable
group by connection_id 
order by [to] asc limit 1
```

Comment: +1, although I think one of your Order By clauses should be on [to].

Comment: Thanks @PhilSandler I was just updating ;)

Comment: @bonCodigo you have to put subqueries in `()` when you use a union query, otherwise you are not allowed to use ORDER BY and LIMIT (they can be applied only once, but for the whole union query). However this does not give the correct result: you have to extract the first `from` field and the last `to` field for every connection_id, ordered by `date` column